# Retrieve date column default values from BINARYDEFVAL column in sys.ecol$

Tags: oracle, plsql, blob

I am trying to retrieve `BLOB` values in `BINARYDEFVAL` column from `sys.col$` table.

The BINARYDEFVAL of `sys.ecol$` table stores default column values in BLOB format. For `VARCHAR2` and `NUMBER` I am able to extract the default column value.

But, for DATE columns when I use `utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(BINARYDEFVAL))` I get some gibberish values like: `xv| (and some special characters`).

Though I can see the default value for one such column is having default value as : `sysdate`.

I think this is not the correct way to extract a default date value.

Please tell me how this can be resolved.

Comment: I'm not familiar with these tables.  Please post link to Oracle Documents that describe these tables.  You should never use undocumented "features".

Comment: Actually the table was already used in a PL/SQL function code by another developer. I found the reference in some blogs/article but not official Oracle documentation. Reference: https://hoopercharles.wordpress.com/2011/09/

Answer (score 2):

As it was already said, use `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS`.

```
create table bp.t1 as select * from dba_objects;
alter table bp.t1 add (d1 date default date'2018-06-13' not null);

select * from ecol$;

   TABOBJ#     COLNUM BINARYDEFVAL      GUARD_ID
---------- ---------- --------------- ----------
     28857         27 7876060D010101    



with function raw_to_date (p_raw raw) return date as 
  l_date date;
begin
  dbms_stats.convert_raw_value(p_raw, l_date);
  return l_date;
end;
select raw_to_date(dbms_lob.substr(binarydefval)) as date_value from ecol$;
/

DATE_VALUE         
-------------------
2018-06-13 00:00:00
```

This will not work for `sysdate`, because it returns the time the column was added.

Meanwhile:

```
select data_default from dba_tab_columns where table_name = 'T1' and column_name = 'D1';

DATA_DEFAULT                                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
date'2018-06-13'
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than relying on Oracle internals that could change, the correct way is to use the `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS` data dictionary view, specifically the `DATA_DEFAULT` column.

Documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/DBA_TAB_COLUMNS.html).

Comment: Thank you Phil. But here the column type of DATA_DEFAULT is LONG. Could you please tell me there are any solutions to extract value from LONG column inline. Meanwhile I will also search for any solution also.

Answer (score 0):

This is true regarding Oracle internals. However, `SYS.ECOL$.BINARYDEFVAL` has different semantics from `SYS.DBA_TAB_COLS.DATA_DEFAULT` (which is `SYS.COL$.DEFAULT$` underneath). So there might exist  special case when you need to check BINARYDEFVAL.

- `SYS.COL$.DEFAULT$` - shows current default value for column in a table.
- `SYS.ECOL$.BINARYDEFVAL` - shows default value of column at time it was added through DDL COLUMN optimization (11gR2 `_add_col_optim_enabled` for `ALTER TABLE ADD DEFAULT NOT NULL`, or 12gR1 `_add_nullable_column_with_default_optim` for null-able columns `ALTER TABLE ADD DEFAULT` ... ). Oracle has to store this value as well, as `DEFAULT` could be later altered to different value, however Oracle could have data with `NULL` values in the NEW COLUMN where it  has to show original add column `DEFAULT` value, not the later altered one.

Check following code

```
CREATE TABLE svc.t_test (V VARCHAR2(30));
INSERT INTO svc.T_test VALUES ('A');
COMMIT;
ALTER TABLE svc.t_test ADD (ID NUMBER DEFAULT 0);
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYS_OP_VECBIT("SYS_NC00002$",0)) hidden_col, v,id FROM svc.t_test;
HIDDEN_COL           
V                            ID
-------------------- -------------------- ----------
                         A                             0
ALTER TABLE svc.t_test MODIFY (ID DEFAULT 10);
INSERT INTO svc.T_test(v) VALUES ('B');
COMMIT;
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYS_OP_VECBIT("SYS_NC00002$",0)) hidden_col, v,id FROM svc.t_test;
HIDDEN_COL           V                            ID
-------------------- -------------------- ----------
                     A                             0
1                    B                            10
```

For the first row in database block, there is still only one column populated, column V. hidden column `SYS_NC00002$` and column `ID` remains `NULL`. Therefore Oracle has to decode internally this `NULL` to 0 and even in case `DEFAULT` will be changed later. Therefore it has to store value 0 in `BINARYDEFVAL` "forever" (unless column is dropped).  For the second row it is different story, it has been populated by value actual (altered) default value 10. It is physically written in DB block and oracle has not more to remember this value (in case of someone alters the default value again in the future).